# How to make res data global in fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch

I have this var that i need to make global so i can use it in another area, i can't find away around, i tried making it global but didn't work. can i get help pls ? :)

```
fetch('http:google.com').then(res => res.json()).then((out) => {
var x = _.filter( out.features, ['status','online']);
console.log('Output: ', x);
}).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

i need to make X global var so i can use in different place in my website. for example in the next place i need just to call it var x and get the data.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you could do this:

Declare it on the window so you can access it elsewhere:

```
window.x = yourResponseHere;
```

Declare the variable in the global scope and then set it within your fetch:

```
var x = ""
fetch('http:google.com').then(res => res.json()).then((out) => {
x = _.filter( out.features, ['status','online']);
console.log('Output: ', x);
}).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: You really should have a look at the _possible duplicate_ in the comments and how [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) work :)